# React single file upload with Node, Express, Multer and store to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-cloud-storage, multer

I have built a website for my 3D project. I want to upload images to the React web and store it in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. It looks like the backend server can send the image to Google Cloud Storage when I hit the request with Postman but does not receive a request to upload image from the frontend. I get the following issues:

```
1) xhr.js:184 POST http://localhost:9001/uploads 500 (Internal Server Error)

2) createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:69)
```

My upload code is in Modeling.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';

export class modeling extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.fileChangedHandler = this.fileChangedHandler.bind(this);
    this.uploadHandler = this.uploadHandler.bind(this);

    this.state={
      selectedFile: ''
    }
  }

  fileChangedHandler = event => {
    this.setState({
      selectedFile: event.target.files[0],
    })
  }

  uploadHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = new FormData() 
    data.append('image', this.state.selectedFile)
    axios.post("http://localhost:9001/uploads", data, { 
    })
      .then(res => { // then print response status
        console.log(res.statusText)
      })
    }
  render(){
    return (
        <h3>Upload a 2D image to get a 3D model</h3>         
        <input className="btn btn-secondary" type="file" onChange={this.fileChangedHandler} />
         <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.uploadHandler} id="renderButton">Uplooad</button>
    )
  }
}

export default modeling
```

My backend code is:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer')

const uploadImage = require('./helpers/helpers')

const app = express()

const multerMid = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  limits: {
    // no larger than 5mb.
    fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
  },
});

app.use(cors());
app.disable('x-powered-by')
app.use(multerMid.single('file'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.post('/uploads', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const myFile = req.file
    const imageUrl = await uploadImage(myFile)

    res
      .status(200)
      .json({
        message: "Upload was successful",
        data: imageUrl
      })
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(500).json({
    error: err,
    message: 'Internal server error!',
  })
  next()
})

app.listen(9001, () => {
  console.log('app now listening for requests!!!')
})
```

I have tested the backend in Postman, uploaded successfully and the image also displayed in my Google Cloud Storage bucket as the picture below
[image: Postman]

Can anyone give me some advice on why my frontend cannot receive the HTTP post request to upload at the URL  "http://localhost:9001/uploads" and how to fix this? I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: When you use arrow functions, there's no need to bind them inside your constructor. Get rid of those two lines after super(props)

Comment: Also, in your axios post request, you need to add a .catch(error => console.log(error))

Comment: it still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding async and await to your function like this?

```
uploadHandler = async (event) => { 
    event.preventDefault() 
    const data = new FormData() 
    data.append('image', 
    this.state.selectedFile) 
    await axios.post("./uploads", 
    data, { }).then(res => { 
    // then print response status 
    console.log(res.statusText) 
    }).catch(error => 
    console.log(error)) 
}
```

Comment: it does not work too. It should be axios.post("http://localhost:9001/uploads") because I put the backend server including the google cloud storage in a different folder at the local host 9001. My client folder is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/3d-tool-zjm5m and my server side folder is https://repl.it/@tuyenphk/PleasantLimegreenRefactoring. Could you go over and help me to figure out it? Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure, I'll take a closer look at it tomorrow, but one thing I noticed is that you are wrapping your buttons inside an <a> tag. Remove those tags and try again, if it doesn't work, I'll check tomorrow

Comment: i think the <a> tag helps a space between 2 buttons. I have tried but "POST http://localhost:9001/uploads 500 (Internal Server Error)" also

Comment: That's not the right use of an <a> tag, use a <div> in that case, also when you use axios.post("localhost:9001/uploads") it can surely work in your local machine, but once you host your code somewhere, it won't, so you need to use a relative path. I can see there are tons of gaps you need to fill first in order to understand properly. I recommend you start by learning the html basics, before diving into more complex subjects. Good luck